# How to point CloudFront to use two ALB's from two different regions (one active region and one DR region)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

Looking for a solution to use two different ALbs from two different regions with CloudFront. I want to instruct CloudFront to use DR ALB in case of a error (5xx) from primary region ALB.
With out cloudfront, its working fine with ALB's and R53 health checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CloudFront's origin failover feature. Basically if your primary origin returns an error (based on the list of codes you specify), it will switch over to the secondary origin. You can see the details and steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html).

Comment: Thank you chamal. Yes i gone through this link before logging this question. I did configured everything as mentioned in the post and i can see the 5xx error as part of the failover but CloudFront unable to serve the content from my DR ALB during this time where my primary ALB was down. I will recheck once more time this setup.